# Selecting components for jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to optimize jquery mobile and select only those components I need with the jquery mobile download builder http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/.

However, I have troubles deciding which components I actually need. The features I need are these:

- Navigation from a page to another
- Basic form elements
- Theming related to the aforementioned features

Form element components I can probably pick up myself but do I for example need 'Global initialization of the library' listed in core components in the download builder page?

Comment: no, you dont necessary need __Global initialization of the library__, if you dont wish jqm to auto-initialize  the whole document. Hence, you should do it manually e.g. text input, you need to call `.textinput()` to initialize the widget.